# Is there a way to identify if gem5 run got over successfully?

Tags: gem5

I have observed that some of my gem5 runs (used bsub to distribute runs) are getting killed, but the stats are getting dumped even when killed. Is there any way to dump stats only when the gem5 run completes successfully?
or 
Is there any way to identify if the run got over successfully?

PS: I am using a traffic generator

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting?

- if gem5 behaved, well, it should set exit status `!= 0` on errors.

  However it doesn't always do so, and behavior has changed in the recent past sometimes for better or worse.

  If you find a failure case that does not set exit status `!= 0`, I recommend that you patch it and send a patch upstream to show devs that this is desired.

  So in general I am forced just grep stdout looking for `--- BEGIN LIBC BACKTRACE ---$` as [done here](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/7a5ca339a356fff98c1537f0b2c5e960757924d8/run#L630).
- `system.panic_on_panic` makes gem5 detect kernel panics on arm and aarch64 in full system by the address of the `panic` symbol, and exits with -6.

  It was not working on X86 when I last tried however, related [see also this](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/7a5ca339a356fff98c1537f0b2c5e960757924d8#exit-gem5-on-panic)
- SE.py does not forward guest exit status... I just [parse stdout for the message `Simulated exit code not 0! Exit code is` again](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/7a5ca339a356fff98c1537f0b2c5e960757924d8/run#L644).

  See also [this info](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/7a5ca339a356fff98c1537f0b2c5e960757924d8#gem5-syscall-emulation-exit-status).

Mailing list thread for this post: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16538.html